# Core 'session is active' errors presenting after ProcessWire site migration

Tags: php, apache, migration, debian, processwire

> Warning: session_name(): Cannot change session name when session is active in /var/www/html/website/wire/core/Session.php on line 143
>
> Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /var/www/html/website/wire/core/Session.php on line 146
>
> Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /var/www/html/website/wire/core/Session.php on line 147
>
> Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /var/www/html/website/wire/core/Session.php on line 148
>
> Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /var/www/html/website/wire/core/Session.php on line 149

PHP 7.3, ProcessWire v.3.0  https://github.com/processwire/processwire/blob/master/wire/core/Session.php

What does this mean, what ini settings should be altered, how do I clear the supposed session?

Answer (score 1):

In a default setup you can remove existing sessions by deleting the folder `site/assets/sessions`. If you store your sessions in the [database](https://processwire.com/docs/security/sessions/), you might have to clear out the `sessions` table in the database.

When migrating Processwire sites, I usually don't migrate the `cache`, `log` and `sessions` folders. They will be regenerated automatically.